# What is the correct Typescript interface for a multidimensional object with variable depth?

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array, interface, javascript-objects

From an api endpoint I get a reply of an object with variable depth. So it may look like this when grouped by date:

```
{
  "2022-10-27": {
    "dim_0": "2022-10-27",
    "clicks": 31627,
    "revenue": 82136,
  },
  "2022-10-26": {
    "dim_0": "2022-10-26",
    "clicks": 11046,
    "revenue": 11588,
  }
}
```

But it can go up to four levels deep, for example when first grouped by associate, then on level two grouped by date, then on level three group by hour:

```
{
  "Associate 1": {
    "2022-10-27": {
      "07": {
        "dim_0": "Associate 1",
        "dim_1": "2022-10-27",
        "dim_2": "07",
        "clicks": 1084,
        "revenue": 1425,
      },
      "06": {
        "dim_0": "Associate 1",
        "dim_1": "2022-10-27",
        "dim_2": "06",
        "clicks": 754,
        "revenue": 1100,
      },
    },
    "2022-10-26": {
      "22": {
        "dim_0": "Associate 1",
        "dim_1": "2022-10-26",
        "dim_2": "22",
        "clicks": 149,
        "revenue": 0,
      },
      "23": {
        "dim_0": "Associate 1",
        "dim_1": "2022-10-26",
        "dim_2": "23",
        "clicks": 141,
        "revenue": 0,
      }
    }
  },
  "Other Associate": {
    "2022-10-27": {
      "04": {
        "dim_0": "Other Associate",
        "dim_1": "2022-10-27",
        "dim_2": "04",
        "clicks": 623,
        "revenue": 0,
      },
      "01": {
        "dim_0": "Other Associate",
        "dim_1": "2022-10-27",
        "dim_2": "01",
        "clicks": 447,
        "revenue": 0,
      },
      "05": {
        "dim_0": "MoarOffers_MULTI_16|18_SIGNUP_3.00_USD_YourSecretHookUp_TIKTOK_READY",
        "dim_1": "2022-10-27",
        "dim_2": "05",
        "clicks": 405,
        "revenue": 0,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While the leaf objects are well defined, the keys change according to the grouping (this could be strings, integers, dates).

How would I write an interface that shows all of the possibilities? So far I've written four interfaces, basically describing every single variant of these variants (i.e. LevelOneObject, LevelTwoObject, LevelThreeObject, LevelFourObject), but that feels very unclean and clunky, because then I have to have all my function be able to handle this giant union type. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure if it is an answer to your question, so I'll post in comment. Best case would be to generate classes from openapi file or GraphQL schema, so you actually write nothing. Your model is good for me, it is explicit, and easy to read, do you really want to write like 10 lines less to make it generic? If it has to evolve differently in the future, it also can be less effective. I personally would apply KISS principle and use your really simple interfaces, you can't go wrong as it is explicit and covers all cases.

Comment: What does `{someobject}` and `{SomeObject}` mean here? Is it pseudocode or is it a [shorthand property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) referring to an undeclared variable?  I can possibly write up a type that generates your `LevelXObject` types given a depth, but I don't understand what goes at the deepest level, or how the keys at each level are chosen.  Could you [edit] to make sure your code is a [mre] I can drop into an IDE? If you do this, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.

Comment: If the keys can be anything and you just have a depth and a leaf type, you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2zLbw); does that work for your use case?  If not, that [mre] would be very helpful.  How should we proceed here? (Again, @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz I've updated my description to make it more clear. I could use your DeepSignatureType, but that would still mean I'd have to create basically four types?!

Comment: Am I supposed to do something more specific than a string index signature for the layers here? I can't tell how to generalize from those key names.  Maybe you could trim the example down to just 2 layers or something and then post your "giant union type" or enough of it so I understand what you're doing?

Comment: Also, when you ask "I'd have to create basically four types?!" does the "⁉" punctuation imply that four is a big number for types?  I don't know if the answer is "yes" or "no" (because I still don't quite understand the use case); I'd say that `DeepIndexSignature<4, Foo>` counts as *one* type, but maybe you mean something else?  But even if so, I'd think that four types isn't a big deal... unless I'm missing something. I must be missing something.  Help!  (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you update here)

Comment: Are you asking for something like `DeepIndexSignature<1|2|3|4, Foo>` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXq4QN)?  Let me know